# Show/Hide div on button click in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

This may be really simple for you guys, but since I'm learning backbone and jquery, I'm having hard time figuring this out.

When the page first loads, I want it to show only one div (out of a few), and start showing other divs when Yes/No button is clicked. I'm also using twitter bootstrap for ui

This is what I have for backbone view:

```
App.Views.Question = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    className: 'question-box hide',

    template: template('questionTemplate'),

    events: {

    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        var editQuestionnaire = this.model.toJSON();
        console.log(this.$el.html(editQuestionnaire));
        this.$el.html(this.template(editQuestionnaire));
        //console.log(this.model);
        return this;
    }
});
```

As you can see, I set the className to 'question-box hide', but it hides all the divs.

Here's my Index.html

```
<div class="bs-docs-example bs-docs-question">
        <span class="badge badge-success"><%= question_id %></span>
        <div class="span3 question-div">
            <h4 class="text-info">
                <%= question %>
            </h4>
            <div class="hs<%= question_id %>"></div> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var id = <%= question_id %>;
                var yes_id = <%= yes_question_id %>;
                var no_id = <%= no_question_id %>; 

                if(id == 1)
                {
                    $('div .question-box').attr('class', 'question-box show');
                }
                if(id != 8 && id != 9 && id != 6)
                {
                    $('.hs<%= question_id %>')
                        .append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes </button>')
                        .append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">No</button>');
                }         

                else if(id == 6)
                {
                    $('.hs<%= question_id %>')
                         .append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK </button>')
                         .append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>');
                }         

            </script>

            <span class="span5"></span>


        <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
```

The project is sort of conditional branching site. So, the first box must always appear. Then depending on the question answered, a different box should appear. (I think I know how to do this. I think I can create a function which will take question_id as an argument, and then display the box. I can put onclick option in button. I haven't tried this yet, though) 
I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you really could avoid js code inside the html file, try to do that inside your view it makes more sense using backbone.

I couldn't understand exactly what you mean. but i have some tips to help you.
If you want show an element when a button is clicked, you can do something like this.

```
//Inside your view
events:
   "click #buton":"showElement"

showElement:->
    @$("#div").addClass("someClassToShowTheDiv")
```

Maybe the problem in your code can be here:
$('div .question-box').attr('class', 'question-box show');

The correct way is:
$('div .question-box').addClass('question-box show');

hope it helps!

Comment: There are 9 questions, each in it's own div. The buttons should also be inside the div. Then, when yes is clicked, it should show another question based on the yes_id which is stored in the backbone collection. So, in order for the click event to fire, I should put the buttons in the index.html, right? But I don't understand how backbone view will know which div to display if yes or no is clicked.

Comment: Yes, you need to have your buttons inside the index.html. When you click on 'yes' button you will tell with div should be displayed using jquery.

Comment: The button works, but my divs still don't do what I want it to do. It either show all or none. I have another view App.View.Questions which has this.collection.each(this.addOne, this) inside render function. I think this is loading all the question to the div from my other view above. How can I fetch only one collection item in backbone?

Comment: add me on skype, maybe i can help you better... xprenan